# Windows Authentication Issues

Tags: c#, session, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm trying to setup a `FormsAuthentication` login and logout with roles. Why is `@User.Identity.Name` returning Windows Domain Username with these configurations set?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Login" loginUrl="~/User/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" protection="All" timeout="90" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

In VS2015 project properties -> development server, Windows Authentication is set to Disabled.

In result, I sometimes get the forms username displaying using `@User.Identity.Name`, but most of the time when I login or logout, I get the Windows Domain Name. I should be getting `user.UserName` in the `@User.Identity.Name` (if I understand what it displays correctly).

In a UserController, I set a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` with an `HttpCookie`.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90), user.RememberMe, user.Roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

if (ticket.IsPersistent)
{
    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
}

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
```

During logout, I set the same cookie to empty, and `Session.Abandon()`.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();

HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);

// clear authentication cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
```

This is how I display the username:

```
@if (User != null)
{
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Logged in as @User.Identity.Name
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
```

I have tried all sorts of things but I'm pulling my hair out here and cannot understand where it is that I am going wrong.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Added to the question. I don't think the cookie is being cleared or overridden, because the web.config has a setting to limit a page to Admin role. It isn't being fired, because the user is always logged in. I want it to use guest state (when I log out it goes to Windows Auth and displays domain name) or `user.UserName` and not Windows Auth. Hope that explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

What you do incorrectly, for sure, is you create **two** auth cookies.

The first one comes from

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and another one from

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.UserName, user.RememberMe);
```

Upon logout, you have similar duplication. This line

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

appends an expired forms cookie to the response but you do it again

```
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And last but not least, if you display the user name, make sure the user is autenticated

```
@if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

otherwise you risk displaying the user name for unauthenticated requests.

What you should do:

1. make sure all your controllers/actions you want to correctly handle authentication are decorated with `Authorize`
2. use an Http debugger (Fiddler, Charles, Burp) to make sure a single authentication cookie is being sent from the server to the client and comes back with consecutive requests.
3. Clear any duplicated pending cookies in the browser if necessary - it's possible that one of your previous *failed* attempts has created a long-lived persistent cookie with your windows user name and the browser sends this pending cookie with every request.

Comment: @WiktorZychla there might be that, but even when I remove Add from login, and SignOut from logout, it still persists on displaying Windows domain username. Browser cookies/cache has been cleared.

Comment: Fiddler tells me that when logging in it is getting set to this weird value `Login=C4BEFC0ED0C83C0B077C8D8FD300F86...` etc. When logging out, the cookie is set to this. `Set-Cookie: Login=; expires=Mon, 22-Aug-2016 10:19:09 GMT; path=/`. There doesn't seem to be any duplicates. It seems to also show `PersistentAuth = true` when the box isn't being ticked.

Comment: @kamil1995b: the `PersistentAuth` header is a clear indication that Windows authentication is still used for some reason. In other words, despite `Forms` being the configured provider, `Windows` is still used. The reason unfortunately cannot be concluded from the facts you presented, we can only speculate. Have you modified the correct `web.config` (the root one rather than the one under `Views` folder)? If yes, can you reproduce this wrong behavior on a simplest app and share the complete code so that it can be examined?

Comment: @YvetteColomb: the OP is still having his app authenticated with Kerberos, the `PersistentAuth` header they receive is a clear indication. Looks like a simple misconfiguration then, nothing related to the code they present, however.